# How to achieve some measure of "privilege separation" with Java web-server?

Tags: java, ssl, jetty, privileges

I'm trying to be proactive around security on my Jetty web-server boxes -- especial with regards to storing SSL key information although I'd like a generic solution.  Apache uses [privilege separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_separation) so that it starts as root so it can read the protected SSL key files (and other secure configuration) and then switches to some common user to actually server HTTP requests.  But Java has no mechanism for doing this.

Any recommendations around how to achieve the same level of security in a Java web application?   My requires include:

- Secret information should only be readable by root.
- Any passwords which unlock keys and the like should not be configured into the code so that someone with the same user level permissions as the server can't get them easily.
- I'm running under Amazon EC2 so I want the security to be as automatic as possible -- i.e. no interactive password entering by operators.

One possibility would be to use ~LDAP to separate the secret information from the application and only bake the LDAP access username/password into the application.  But I'm looking for a better solution.

Thanks for any information.

**Edit:**

I'd hoped for solutions that covered SSL but took into account other secrets that I wanted to limit access to.  I did not make that clear enough in my initial post.

Comment: If you are talking about Application level security, you should take a look at Spring security.

Comment: Java have his own security manager, look for http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Jetty-Policy. You can configure your jvm to allow read passwords/private keys from certain classes/jars. That solution does not protect from other processes from same user, but you can forbid jvm to launch new processes and run jetty from separate user.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @AlexanderKudrevatykh.  I was hoping to get a solution to restrict Unix user access as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I appreciate both @Joakim and @Tony's answers, I was hoping for a more generic solution that covered general password protection without JNI/Jetty specific features and more generic than just SSL secret key protection.

The best solution I can come up with is a small C wrapper program that was setuid root.  It would:

1. Starts up and read in a collection of secret information from root protected files on disk into memory.  It should immediately encrypt the secret information in memory (see below).
2. Switches from root to the unprivileged user running the application.
3. Forks and exec's JVM with the appropriate application arguments.
4. Writes the encryption key and the encrypted passwords in via STDIN.
5. When the JVM boots, it immediately reads in the encrypted secret information from STDIN.
6. One they are read the wrapper application will terminate.

As an extension, the small C wrapper could stay running and provide access to the JVM to system resources by using a simple line based protocol over STDIN/STDOUT.  This would give the JVM access to other protected resources on the system in a controlled manner.

Here are some other thoughts on possible solutions.

- A service started at boot time by init.d script that runs as root and serves a collection of secret keys to the JVMs starting up by some web service or though some FIFO file or something.  After the first request it would shutdown or after some number of seconds after boot.
- LDAP is certainly better than having the secret foo on the box itself -- readable by the application user.  As an alteration to the solution above, the setuid program could inject the LDAP password into application so it would not live in user readable space.

As always, both applications would need to protect the passwords in memory.  Storing them in system sockets or splitting them up into noncontiguous memory blocks is always a good idea.  You could also generate a secret key and encrypt them in memory as well.

Comment: Sounds like a lot of trouble to go to in order to avoid running something that is well-proven, supported by the community, and gets the job done.

Comment: Again @TonyK., I was looking for a solution that included non-SSL passwords and the like.  For example, I need the access-key and secret-key to access Amazon S3.  Is there a generic solution for that?

Answer (score 3):

The apache technique you described is provided by the optional **jetty-setuid** features.

See http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/setuid.html

Comment: Thanks for this @Joakim.  I was hoping to be able to run Jetty directly wired and without the JNI requirements.  But maybe a good solution for others.  +1

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you bake anything like a password into source (which is stored on disk), you've circumvented security. So, storing the information in LDAP isn't going to help.

I'm not convinced the setuid feature is going to help either, in that it is there purely for accessing ports in the networking code, and might not do the setuid at the correct time (after opening the SSL files). Of course, you could test that by protecting the files as root and see if it can open them...if so, you're golden and Joakim's answer is the best option.

What we do is set up a simple apache or nginx server to front the JVM through a proxy, then run jetty under it's own UID. Then you can take advantage of the setuid SSL security that is already well-tested in either of those servers. We also have some other requirements that this also helps solve, but I would probably choose to do it this way even if we didn't.

The nginx config is also pretty darn simple:

```
server {
    listen       192.168.1.1:443;
    server_name  www.mydomain.com;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;

    ssl                  on;
    ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl/server.key;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/ssl.access.log  main;

    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    location /AppPath {
       proxy_pass http://jettyhost:8080/AppPath;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Hadn't heard of nginx. Looks pretty simple. I was hoping for a more generic solution but some good points here.  Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect that, because of the multi-platform nature of Java, there hasn't been much emphasis on Unix-based techniques like what exists in Apache Httpd, since these may not necessarily be applicable to all platforms on which Java can run.

In Java, privilege separation is in-built, by the means of the security manager. Whether this is as good as the root/non-root separation, I'm not sure (there can always be bugs). However, its policies are, in principle, capable of expressing more subtle access rules than just the distinction between a root and non-root users.

Jetty had this, but this was apparently [dropped in Jetty 9](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Secure_Mode) (you can still use a security manager, but you may have to write your own policies and do a bit more of the work to implement them in the container).

The [Jetty Policy document](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Jetty-Policy) also states:

> Normally a user trusts the application they are developing or are trusting enough to deploy a webapp into an instance of jetty. If you don't know that you need to use the security manager setup, you probably don't.

I'm not sure I'd agree with that. Indeed, if there's a webapp I suspect to be malicious, I won't run it anyway, but using a security manager is also about containing potential security bugs. Anyone can write bugs, even good programmers. Having a mechanism that restrict possible actions by webapps is certainly a good thing.

A sensible policy would certainly prevent webapps from accessing the config files and the keystores.

I would also argue that this webapp separation is also at the core of the notion of "container" (although security is only one of the purposes of this separation, it seems to have been lost).

In fairness, it's not as straightforward as the separation offered by the root/forking mechanism in Apache Httpd. The power of Java security policies also brings complexity. I suppose these features are generally not well understood, and thus little used. Using Apache Httpd (or Nginx, or others) as a reverse proxy tends to be a simpler solution for the purpose of protecting the private keys.

Another way you could look into is using a PKCS#11 keystore. This is supported by the JRE. Hardware Security Modules would help prevent your private keys to be copied. (From a Java point of view, you get a `PrivateKey` instance that delegates the cryptographic operations to the PKCS#11 library, but from which you cannot extract the private data at all.)

Of course, this is a problem when you don't have access to the hardware, but there are software implementations of this (looking up "Software HSM" might seem odd, but it will bring a few results). Not all of them will let you have the separation you're after, but some should (effectively, by communicating with another entity holding the private key, which you could potentially run as another user). I haven't tried it, but [this one](http://www.clizio.com/download.html) might be of interest.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer Bruno +1.  The Java security model is certainly good for protecting various different elements of your application that you don't trust.  I was hoping for answers that were more generic.  But thanks again.